# ElementTree findtext doesn't find leaf nodes

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree to scan an XML string pulled from a text file.

```
<root>
    <branch_a>
        <leaf>foo</leaf>
    </branch_a>
    <branch_b>
        <another_leaf>bar</another_leaf>
    </branch_b>
</root>
```

When I parse it and try to find the leaf nodes, I don't get any result:

```
>>> elem_tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
>>> leaf_text = elem_tree.findtext('leaf')
>>> leaf_text is None
True
```

But when I traverse the tree, everything works fine:

```
>>> elem_tree.findtext('branch_a/leaf')
'foo'

>>> branch = elem_tree.find('branch_a')
>>> branch.findtext('leaf')
'foo'
```

Is there a way to have ElementTree scan the whole tree for me?  My branch names are dynamic, the leaf I'm looking for could live under any branch.

I was able to do this with minidom, but ran into other limitations.  Here's what I was doing there, for reference (error checking stripped out).

```
>>> xml_doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)
>>> leaf_node = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('leaf')
>>> leaf_node[0].firstChild.nodeValue
'foo'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findtext` uses an ElementTree style path statement, so you were only scanning the immediate children. This will scan the entire tree (see [element xpath](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm)):

```
leaf_text = elem_tree.findtext('.//leaf')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it this way:

```
leaf_text = elem_tree.findall('.//leaf')

for x in range(0, len(leaf_text)):
    print leaf_text[x].text
```